# Поиск элемента selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Только начал изучать selenium, подскажите, как я могу найти на странице следующий элемент: `<div class="im-mess--text wall_module _im_log_body">` и получить его содержимое в виде текста?

[image: div class]

Comment: не забывайте отметить ответ, если вам помогли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(DIV_XPATH).text`
, где
`DIV_XPATH = '//div[@class="im-mess--text wall_module _im_log_body"]'`
или
`DIV_XPATH = '//div[contains(@class, "wall_module")]'` (если важны не все классы или классы у элемента меняются)

Comment: Не понимаю, что я делаю не так, но на выходе получаю пустую строку в обоих случаях

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, можно хотябы ссылку на страничку где этот div?

Comment: div из любого диалога в вк, где есть порядочное кол-во сообщений, т.е,
https://vk.com/im?sel=id

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, могу предположить, что нужный элемент не успевает подгрузиться на момент выполнения поиска, для ожидания загрузки элемента можно использовать `WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 0.05).until(func)`

Comment: у меня в коде есть `sleep(5)`
Знаю, что плохой пример, но страница вся загружается

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, в консоли браузера при такой записи `$x('//div[(@class="im-mess--text wall_module _im_log_body"]')[0].innerText` выводится текст, так что селектор работает вроде

Comment: Вот мой код:
`DIV_XPATH = '//div[@class="im-mess--text wall_module _im_log_body"]'
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(DIV_XPATH).text
print(text)`

до сих пор получаю:

`Unable to locate element: //div[@class="im-mess--text wall_module _im_log_body"]`

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, скорее всего это потому что таких элементов на странице много, замените `find_element_by_xpath` на `find_elements_by_xpath` (вроде так)

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, в итоге должен получиться список элементов и доступ к тексту `elem_list[0].text`

Comment: По какой-то причине получается список длиной 0
Пробовал различные вариации DIV_XPATH

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90484/discussion-between-clark-devlin-and-chocolateswan).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
div_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.im-mess--text.wall_module._im_log_body").text
```

Comment: Ну, ошибки никакой не выдает, однако, когда хочу вывести это, т.е,
`print(div_text)` , то ничего не получаю, просто пустая строка